# Is pthread_setcanceltype and pthread_setcancelstate for another thread possible?

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, unix, pthreads

Are there any functions that are similar to pthread_setcancelstate and pthread_setcanceltype but more general in a way that I can pass in any 'pthread_t' reference ID or 'struct pthread*' to it, and performs these functions into the passed-in thread known by its ID? and if there aren't such functions, would there be any way to hack into the library and make similar functions?

Comment: You can make them any way you want. You can design any mechanism you want to tell other threads to do particular things and make them do what they're told to do. *You are writing all the code.* Nothing prevents you from doing this using any mechanism whatsoever.

Comment: This sort of functionality does not exist, AFAIK. It would also be inherently racy, so its value is more than dubious.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz But, can you show me a particular way to implement such function, please, because I tried getting the 'struct pthread*' from 'pthread_t' value, and tried to change the 'cancelhandling' or 'parent_cancelhandling' of the struct, but that did not do anything useful (tried doing so in GDB, as trying to set the fields at compile time gave me compiler error)??

Comment: @falhumai Your question reduces to "how do I make a thread do something". That the "something" is change cancellation modes is just a minor detail. It's not about the details of cancellation, it's about the general question of how you make a thread do something. Don't much in the details of cancellation, figure out how you're going to make another thread do something first.